# Writing a custom main() function with Embedded Cython modules in C

Tags: c, makefile, cython

I am fairly new to the Cython world, but I know C and Python well. I am trying to use Cython to compile a Python code into C, but I need to write my own main() function in C.

I have only found one example online of a code that is compiled from a C program that calls a function written in Python/Cython, but they don't tell you how to compile it. See that example here: https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/embedding.html

To be clear, I would prefer being able to compile a Python code and call it from C rather than running the Python interpreter in C.

To compile this myself, I am using Rocky Linux running the default Python version (3.6.8).

I am using the two codes seen referenced in the above example with no modifications. To compile these codes, I started with the UNIX Makefile from the github link that is mentioned in the example and added a line of code to compile the "embedded_main.c" code:

```
# Makefile for creating our standalone Cython program
PYTHON := python3
PYVERSION := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import sys; print(sys.version[:3])")
PYPREFIX := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)")

INCDIR := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_inc())")
PLATINCDIR := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=True))")
LIBDIR1 := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'))")
LIBDIR2 := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBPL'))")
PYLIB := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBRARY')[3:-2])")

CC := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('CC'))")
LINKCC := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('LINKCC'))")
LINKFORSHARED := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('LINKFORSHARED'))")
LIBS := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBS'))")
SYSLIBS :=  $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('SYSLIBS'))")

.PHONY: paths all clean test

paths:
    @echo "PYTHON=$(PYTHON)"
    @echo "PYVERSION=$(PYVERSION)"
    @echo "PYPREFIX=$(PYPREFIX)"
    @echo "INCDIR=$(INCDIR)"
    @echo "PLATINCDIR=$(PLATINCDIR)"
    @echo "LIBDIR1=$(LIBDIR1)"
    @echo "LIBDIR2=$(LIBDIR2)"
    @echo "PYLIB=$(PYLIB)"
    @echo "CC=$(CC)"
    @echo "LINKCC=$(LINKCC)"
    @echo "LINKFORSHARED=$(LINKFORSHARED)"
    @echo "LIBS=$(LIBS)"
    @echo "SYSLIBS=$(SYSLIBS)"

embedded: embedded.o
    $(LINKCC) -o $@ $^ -L$(LIBDIR1) -L$(LIBDIR2) -l$(PYLIB) $(LIBS) $(SYSLIBS) $(LINKFORSHARED)

embedded.o: embedded.c
    $(CC) -c $^ -I$(INCDIR) -I$(PLATINCDIR)

### Added to compile custom C function, 'embedded_main.c' ###
embedded_main: embedded.o embedded_main.c
    gcc -o $@ $^ -L/usr/inlcude/python3.6m/ -lpython3.6m -I /usr/include/python3.6m/
#############################################################


CYTHON := cython.py
embedded.c: embedded.pyx
    @$(PYTHON) $(CYTHON) --embed embedded.pyx

all: embedded

clean:
    @echo Cleaning Demos/embed
    @rm -f *~ *.o *.so core core.* embedded.c embedded test.output

test: clean all
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LIBDIR1):$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./embedded > test.output
    $(PYTHON) assert_equal.py embedded.output test.output
```

When I run "make embedded_main" in the terminal, I get the following:

```
$ make embedded_main
gcc -o embedded_main embedded.o embedded_main.c -L/usr/include/python3.6m/ -python3.6m -I /usr/include/python3.6m/
/tmp/ccTNbcJ0.o: In function `main':
embedded_main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
embedded.o:embedded.c:(.text+0x1c07): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:43: embedded_main] Error 1
```

I understand that Cython creates the "embedded.c" with a main() structure, but I want to be able to instead link this c program with the aforementioned "embedded_main.c". Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you just need to drop the `--embed` argument to Cython (its purpose is to generate `main`) and it should probably work

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help. I removed the --embed flag and was able to compile the embedded_main executable! I will update the Makefile in my question with the Makefile that works. Thanks again!

Comment: It's better to leave your question as is and post the working makefile in an _answer_! Glad it worked though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of DavidW's comment, I removed the --embed flag from the embedded.c line. Here is the working makefile with this minor change:

```
# Makefile for creating our standalone Cython program
PYTHON := python3
PYVERSION := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import sys; print(sys.version[:3])")
PYPREFIX := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)")

INCDIR := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_inc())")
PLATINCDIR := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=True))")
LIBDIR1 := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'))")
LIBDIR2 := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBPL'))")
PYLIB := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "from distutils import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBRARY')[3:-2])")

CC := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('CC'))")
LINKCC := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('LINKCC'))")
LINKFORSHARED := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('LINKFORSHARED'))")
LIBS := $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBS'))")
SYSLIBS :=  $(shell $(PYTHON) -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('SYSLIBS'))")

.PHONY: paths all clean test

paths:
    @echo "PYTHON=$(PYTHON)"
    @echo "PYVERSION=$(PYVERSION)"
    @echo "PYPREFIX=$(PYPREFIX)"
    @echo "INCDIR=$(INCDIR)"
    @echo "PLATINCDIR=$(PLATINCDIR)"
    @echo "LIBDIR1=$(LIBDIR1)"
    @echo "LIBDIR2=$(LIBDIR2)"
    @echo "PYLIB=$(PYLIB)"
    @echo "CC=$(CC)"
    @echo "LINKCC=$(LINKCC)"
    @echo "LINKFORSHARED=$(LINKFORSHARED)"
    @echo "LIBS=$(LIBS)"
    @echo "SYSLIBS=$(SYSLIBS)"

embedded: embedded.o
    $(LINKCC) -o $@ $^ -L$(LIBDIR1) -L$(LIBDIR2) -l$(PYLIB) $(LIBS) $(SYSLIBS) $(LINKFORSHARED)

embedded.o: embedded.c
    $(CC) -c $^ -I$(INCDIR) -I$(PLATINCDIR)

### Added to compile custom C function, 'embedded_main.c' ###
embedded_main: embedded.o embedded_main.c
    gcc -o $@ $^ -L/usr/inlcude/python3.6m/ -lpython3.6m -I /usr/include/python3.6m/
#############################################################


CYTHON := cython.py
embedded.c: embedded.pyx
    @$(PYTHON) $(CYTHON) embedded.pyx

all: embedded

clean:
    @echo Cleaning Demos/embed
    @rm -f *~ *.o *.so core core.* embedded.c embedded test.output

test: clean all
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LIBDIR1):$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./embedded > test.output
    $(PYTHON) assert_equal.py embedded.output test.output
```